# Convert .pem to .bin in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pem, bin

can anyone tell me the correct command to convert the private key .pem to a .bin file? I just try the following command but it don't work for me:

```
Openssl rsa -inform der -in My_PrivateKey.bin -outform pem -out My_PrivateKey.pem
```

Comment: If you are trying to convert from PEM do DER (binary), your command is backwards. You should user `-inform pem` and `-outform der` instead. Also, if your input private key is in the PKCS#8 format, your command will convert it to PKCS#1. If you want to keep the PKCS#8 format, you should use the `openssl pkcs8` command instead of `openssl rsa`.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, should you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a private key from PEM to DER (binary), you can use the following commands, depending on which format you want (PKCS#1 or PKCS#8).

For RSA PKCS#1:

`openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -out private_key_pkcs1.der -outform der`

For encrypted PKCS#8:

`openssl pkcs8 -in private_key.pem -out private_key_pkcs8_encrypted.der -outform der -topk8`

For plain PKCS#8:

`openssl pkcs8 -in private_key.pem -out private_key_pkcs8_plain.der -outform der -nocrypt -topk8`

Comment: My private certificate is a file .bin and contains something looks like this:

誡Ờɧ肁瘗敀䎔ￒ⌗촨⫿屨᪨ご慶퇂䬗掎ꜫ홗꙼軓櫐窮ణ諰᠃扯䂈♸肺ﱴ⤸ᶱ꩹궀偿녁✟㿭豟뿁虢넌蒆侂쌔始ꈩ즱捧൉藳㣛長슟烪ĳ끼哥⑥㪖퉡㡇藁脂ᾞ칲徯ᾃ眴䭯璝㝔⨙痪갘ꣁ懯ꄦ뾰婚誡Ờɧ肁瘗敀䎔ￒ⌗촨⫿屨᪨ご慶퇂䬗掎ꜫ홗꙼軓櫐窮ణ諰᠃扯䂈♸肺ﱴ⤸ᶱ꩹궀偿녁✟㿭豟뿁虢넌蒆侂쌔始ꈩ즱捧൉藳㣛長슟烪ĳ끼哥⑥㪖퉡㡇藁脂ᾞ칲徯ᾃ眴䭯璝㝔⨙痪갘ꣁ懯ꄦ뾰婚濏氕憤ꖳ쵼袣㩨쇸閗㓮ࢗ㤽ꊄ㯲豗梷ད葸㺿᷐賲 鱼�轣ⵅ戦䵏籕뵙铀�ퟵ色낃ｿ玠棯ⴞ橸䰗몊ુഊ˓膁쿧᫩㟇鿬䍵ɑ걋泅ᡇ淣莞㠈㌇ㄸᤩ풋⽸佑쭫᥎蜒ꗞ汉ᒫ㿬�絑숡瀺｀堪塚蝯

Do you know witch format is that?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, your question asks how to convert from PEM to BIN, but looks like you have a binary file and wants to convert it to PEM (?). Either way, you can check the format of your file using the following command: `openssl parseasn1 -inform der -in private_key.bin`. If you don't get an error, it's a binary file (DER).

Comment: @WillyKelly You must be joking. If you reveal the content of your private key to the public, it becomes useless.

Comment: obviously that is not the real private key @doug65536