# Thales HSM Import Public Key (EO) error '04'

Tags: java, security, rsa, hsm

I am sending this command with a DER encoded public RSA key.

`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~%#B00N00`

his is just the header `HSM-`, the command `EO` and the `02` denoting "DER encoding for ASN.1 Public Key (INTEGER using unsigned representation)". Followed by the encoded DER itself and then the Key block header ~%#B00N00.

Error 04 means "Public key does not conform to encoding rules".

This is a example obtained via Thales ( HSM supplier) and the only diference is they are using hsm terminal, and my implemententation is via Java sending the message via Socket.

If anyone know something please help.

In advice, they inform me is the public Key is in ASCII and i have to convert to binary Data

Comment: So what prevents you from converting the key to binary? Have you done a web search for converting the key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert .pem to .bin in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835377/convert-pem-to-bin-in-openssl)

Comment: Hi Robert, when i try to convert to binary ( 0101001010101010) the HSM answer me the request is to long

Answer (score 0):

Had the a similar issue with some other commands. I had to convert all characters excluding the public key from ASCII to hex. Then from there I pulled it all together and did a conversion from hex to ASCII. So your command code EO looks like this 454f
Encoding rule 02 looks like 3032

This little method helped me with the conversion

```
public static String hexToAscii(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2) {
        String str = input.substring(i, i + 2);
        result.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

There is probably a smarter way of doing this but it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Eduardo thanks for the answer, the problem as you notice is some commands need the command in "hex format" but some not, all depend in the documentation specified the public key (for example ) is in bytes or plain text

Comment: Yeah, that is the frustrating part about the Thales command set. Best option is to have a method for each command type that performs the required "hex format"